# Flutter cannot find module barcode_scan;

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

i'm new to flutter and try to create a barcode app. To Scan barcodes i'm using this library:   barcode_scan: "^0.0.4". On Android everything is working fine but xcode cannot find my module. I think i'm doing something wrong because some of my packages werent found only in xcode. The way i added those dependencies was, i added the dependencies into my pubspec.yaml file like this:

```
dependencies:
 flutter:
  sdk: flutter

 cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
 barcode_scan: "^0.0.4"
 url_launcher:
 validators:
 flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.2
```

Afterwards i run pub get on android studio. Did i forgot something on the ios side? My Project includes swift support. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use on iOS, you must add the the camera usage description to your Info.plist

```
<dict>
    <!-- ... -->
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Camera permission is required for barcode scanning.</string>
    <!-- ... -->
</dict>
```

Also try to use the latest version of the barcode_scan plugin in your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
    # ...
    barcode_scan: any
```

Latest version had some additional implementation works in Android. Check the official doc [here](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan)

Comment: i added the description to my info.plist but the error stays the same

Comment: what is your flutter channel?

Comment: what do you mean with channel?

Comment: could you try switching to the master channel